# Added /amp to end of pagination url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, permalinks, amp-html

I need added amp to wordpress. All done, but I have some trouble.

Paginations in template looks like that:

```
href="http://localhost/category/uncategorized/amp/page/2/"
```

I need to do like that:

```
href="http://localhost/category/uncategorized/page/2/amp/
```

How to add /amp In the end of paginations?  Any ideas?

In template I call `function next_posts_link() & previous_posts_link();`

Comment: are you develop amp by your self?